# IPFS is a good alternative to save pdf to hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, ipfs

I am creating a hyperledger network that is already working, it has a chaincode in typescript and an api client written in nodejs, so far the data that I am uploading has a field/value. But at the moment I have the requirement to upload PDF files, doing some research I found that an alternative is to use a private IPFS network, and inside hyperledger I store the hash generated when storing the file, but I would like to know if this is a good way to store this type of files, respecting all the characteristics of a blockchain network such as immutability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPFS is a [good fit](https://docs.ipfs.io/concepts/usage-ideas-examples/#blockchain-use-cases) for storing large data offchain. IPFS files addressed using its hash and thus are immutable. One thing to note is that the data added to IPFS are not encrypted by default. You have to implement additional encryption if some data security is needed.